# Deserializing JSON with Table Columns and Rows C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON that I received from our ERP. It is presenting an embedded table in the JSON that is returned.

JSON:

```
{
    "outputs": {},
    "tables": [
        {
            "columns": [
                "Order_No",
                "Order_Line_No",
                "Release_Status_Key",
                "Release_Type_Key",
                "Priority_Key",
                "Part_Key",
                "Unit_Price",
                "Price_Unit",
                "Quantity",
                "Quantity_Variance_Plus",
                "Quantity_Variance_Minus",
                "Quantity_Unit",
                "Customer_Due_Date",
                "Required_Ship_Date",
                "Preliminary_Due_Date",
                "Confirmed_Due_Date",
                "Due_Date",
                "Ship_Date",
                "Note",
                "Printed_Note",
                "Confirmed",
                "Part_No_Revision",
                "Allow_Job_Creation",
                "PO_No",
                "Quantity_Shipped"
            ],
            "rows": [
                [
                    "",
                    "2019090426",
                    3903,
                    2110,
                    null,
                    2268542,
                    0.684700,
                    "ea",
                    429.0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "EDI Automatic 862 Aug 29 2019  7:21PM",
                    "",
                    0,
                    "107771 REV:0",
                    0,
                    "TMMK",
                    429
                ],
                [
                    "",
                    "2019090426",
                    3903,
                    2110,
                    null,
                    2268542,
                    0.754100,
                    "ea",
                    429.0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "EDI Automatic 862 Aug 29 2019  7:21PM",
                    "",
                    0,
                    "107771 REV:0",
                    0,
                    "TMMK",
                    429
                ],
                [
                    "",
                    "2019090426",
                    3903,
                    2110,
                    null,
                    2268542,
                    0.675500,
                    "ea",
                    429.0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "EDI Automatic 862 Aug 29 2019  7:21PM",
                    "",
                    0,
                    "107771 REV:0",
                    0,
                    "TMMK",
                    429
                ],
                [
                    "",
                    "2019090426",
                    3903,
                    2110,
                    null,
                    2268542,
                    0.675500,
                    "ea",
                    429.0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "EDI Automatic 862 Aug 29 2019  7:21PM",
                    "",
                    0,
                    "107771 REV:0",
                    0,
                    "TMMK",
                    429
                ],
                [
                    "",
                    "2019090426",
                    3903,
                    2110,
                    null,
                    2268542,
                    0.607500,
                    "ea",
                    429.0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "EDI Automatic 862 Aug 29 2019  7:21PM",
                    "",
                    0,
                    "107771 REV:0",
                    0,
                    "TMMK",
                    429
                ],
                [
                    "",
                    "2019090426",
                    3903,
                    2110,
                    null,
                    2268542,
                    0.764600,
                    "ea",
                    429.0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    null,
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "2019-09-03T16:36:00Z",
                    "EDI Automatic 862 Aug 29 2019  7:21PM",
                    "",
                    0,
                    "107771 REV:0",
                    0,
                    "TMMK",
                    429
                ]
            ],
            "rowLimitExceeded": false
        }
    ],
    "transactionNo": "26108"
}
```

I've tried to deserialize it with a class that represents the Table that is embedded in the JSON:

```
    class WSResult
    {
        public string Order_No { get; set; }
        public string Order_Line_No { get; set; }
        public int Release_Status_Key { get; set; }
        public int Release_Type_Key { get; set; }
        public int Priority_Key { get; set; }
        public int Part_Key { get; set; }
        public decimal Unit_Price { get; set; }
        public string Price_Unit { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int Quantity_Variance_Plus { get; set; }
        public int Quantity_Variance_Minus { get; set; }
        public string Quantity_Unit { get; set; }
        public string Customer_Due_Date { get; set; }
        public string Required_Ship_Date { get; set; }
        public string Preliminary_Due_Date { get; set; }
        public string Confirmed_Due_Date { get; set; }
        public string Due_Date { get; set; }
        public string Ship_Date { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string Printed_Note { get; set; }
        public int Confirmed { get; set; }
        public string Part_No_Revision { get; set; }
        public int Allow_Job_Creation { get; set; }
        public string PO_No { get; set; }
        public int Quantity_Shipped { get; set; }

    }
       var Response = client.UploadString(Url, JSON);
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new ColumnarDataToListConverter<WSResult>() } };
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WSResult>>(Response, settings);
        MessageBox.Show(list[0].Part_Key.ToString());
        foreach (WSResult item in list)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Release_Status_Key.ToString());
        }
    public class ColumnarDataToListConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(List<T>);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null;
            var list = existingValue as List<T> ?? new List<T>();
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            var columns = obj["columns"] as JArray;
            var data = obj["rows"] as JArray;
            if (data == null)
                return list;
            list.AddRange(data
                .Select(item => new JObject(columns.Zip(item, (c, v) => new JProperty((string)c, v))))
                .Select(o => o.ToObject<T>(serializer)));
            return list;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

The JSON fails to deserialize.

When I tried to create a class from the JSON via Paste Special I get this:

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Outputs outputs { get; set; }
        public Table[] tables { get; set; }
        public string transactionNo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Outputs
    {
    }

    public class Table
    {
        public string[] columns { get; set; }
        public object[][] rows { get; set; }
        public bool rowLimitExceeded { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The past special is functioning correctly here. The JSON output from your ERP will not map to your WSResult without custom deserialization.

Comment: You're asking for a structure that simply doesn't exist in that JSON string. The generated classes reflect the *actual* data. `rows` is an array of arrays in that string and contains mixed data. It can only be an `object[][]`. You'll have to map those classes to those you want with custom code

Comment: The structure of your models has to match the structure of the JSON you are trying to parse from. Because your ERP is using this frankly bizarre form to output their data as you don't have much choice but to deserialize to what you got from `Paste Special` and then do additional coding to get it into a sensible format. The problem with the models you made is that you are attempting to use the values from the `columns` object as keys in your root object. This would work if the ERP was giving you sensible JSON but they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all of the direction that was given to help me answer this question.

I ended up doing this:
It is going to be used to build an insert string for a SQL QUERY

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(Response);
foreach (var item in rootObject.tables)
    {
       int rows = item.rows.GetLength(0);
       int columns = item.rows[0].GetLength(0);
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        while (row++ < rows-1)
        {

            while (column++ < columns-1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.columns[column] + ":" + item.rows[row][column]);
            }
            column = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in root.data.alertContext?.SearchResults?.tables)
        {
            int rows = item.rows.Count;
            int columns = item.rows[0].Count;
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < columns ; column++)
                {
                    
                    log.LogInformation(""+item.columns[column].name + ":" + item.rows[row][column]);

                }
            }
        }
```